# Wix Form submission to Google Sheet

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a code by which whenever a user on my Wix Site submits a Form, the form data gets submitted to my Google Sheet as well.

I followed this article https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175 to create my Web App on Google Sheet

I am having problem entering the code on my website to construct an AJAX request to the URL for my web app/script.

```
var $form = $('form#test-form'),
    url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890/exec'

$('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $form.serializeObject()
  }).success(
    // do something
  );
})
```

The above code shows the form id but on my wix site I do not have a form id, just input field ids and a dataset ID.

I am not a professional so cannot explain properly but can someone please help me if they understand my situation.

Comment: What error does it throw ?

Comment: I have not tried it yet. I just want to know how i should implement this type of code on my wix site